# I get an error when I try to construct a pandas panel

Tags: python, pandas, panel

OK, I am trying to construct a pandas panel. My input data is "All the shares prices in the National Stock Exchange index (NIFTY) for August 2015". There are about 1500 top shares multiply by (open price, high, low, close, volume) multiply by number of days for which the data is available (approx 21 days).

My code is:

```
for files in glob.glob('*.txt')
   for data in files:
      frame = pd.read_csv(data)
      df = pd.append(frame)
matrix3d = pd.append(df)
matrix3d.head(10)
```

I am getting an error... File E does not exist

Comment: Could you print the file name in `data` to see if it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glob.glob()` returns a list of filenames. Example -

```
>>> glob.glob('*.txt')
['a.txt', 'abcd.txt']
```

So, in your code `files` is actually the complete filename for each `*.txt` . When you again iterate over it, you are actually iterating over each character. Like -

```
>>> for file in glob.glob('a.txt'):
...     for data in file:
...             print(data)
...
a
.
t
x
t
```

And then you are trying to call `pd.read_csv()` on it. It would not work, unless you have a csv by that name in the current working directory.

I guess the second iteration `data` one is not needed. You should simply try -

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for files in glob.glob('*.txt')
    frame = pd.read_csv(data)
    df = df.append(frame)
```

Please note I changed it from `pd.append()` to `df.append()` , there is no append function directly in pandas module , there is only [`pandas.DataFrame.append()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) (or `series.append()` , but I guess you maybe wanting `df.append` for your case) .